# Accidentally deleted files an hour ago with rm - ideas for recovery?

Tags: osx, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted files on my MAC under my website folder

`/Library/Server/Documents/mysite`

I have a copy of the folders on my remote server except for about 30 files I recently created. Most of these new files are `.php`, `.js`, and `.html`.

Also, most of these files have certain strings like `somestring` as well as strings related to a given string like `somestring_plusotherstring`

Maybe with dd or something I can rebuild these files?

Been trying third part tools like `EaseUS`, and `DiskDrill` but they don't seem to be searching under `/Library`. They are finding a ton of stuff, but in their `documents` result list they are not showing any `php` or `js` files.

I am currently waiting for `dd` to make a byte for byte copy of the MAC system drive to a file called `backup.data`. After that, hoping to have some clear path ahead to see about recovering.

Anyway, hoping for some good advice!

thanks,
Brian

Comment: Restore from TimeMachine? Is there a particular reason this question is tagged with [tag:linux]?

Comment: Time Machine stores backups locally as well as on an external disk, assuming you have it active in the first place at all.  On a side note, since you're dealing with text source files, I *highly* recommend you begin using Git for version control.

Comment: If you want to recover data it is important that you no longer use the harddisk. Maybe you can use `photorec` to search for lost data. Recovery tools may not be able to find out the original file name, so they might guess the file type based on the data and create a generic name like `file123456.html` or even `file123456.txt`.

Comment: I hadn't been using TimeMachine unfortunately...

Comment: Regarding the tagging, I had read about linux recovery tools and figured they would apply to MAC.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, I have no Mac/OSX experience.) In Linux you can filter [ascii] text from raw data with `strings`.

```
strings -w disk_or_file | grep 'uniquestring'
```

`disk_or_file` should be the raw data that contains your text files somewhere, and `grep` should be looking for an unique string that only occurs in the file you are looking for.

You can add `-C 100` to grep to also output 100 lines before/after that unique string. If your files had more than 100 lines, adapt the number accordingly.

You can add `-t d` to `strings` to also output the byte position the string was found. That way you can use a hex editor or dd or other tools to inspect data around this position directly without the `strings` filter lens. (May be important if your file is not ascii.)

If your unique string is at least 8 characters long, you can add `-n 8` to `strings` to stop it from printing shorter strings. If your unique string is longer adapt this number accordingly (helps performance).

The filenames as well as the exact file boundaries have to be recovered manually. Like other file carving approaches, this only restores file contents.

If this file was not copied over but edited with many intermediate 'Save file' steps, it's also possible to come across incomplete versions of your files. If possible, pick the unique string as one of the function names you added in later versions.

Comment: Hi, I have an image file of the disk, it is 250GB. Is that what I would have to perform the strings command on? Would that actually allow me to pull up the entire file or at this point am I just going to get the string data itself not reconstructed in a containing file?

Comment: strings returns a stream of strings with no start end but perhaps you can add markers with `--output-separator` option. that and grep usually adds its own separators provided there's more than `-C x` lines between occurences. And yes, this approach requires quite a lot of manual post-editing to turn it back into properly named files.

Comment: I ran `strings` and it only returned a few lines. Since I just deleted these files and haven't done anything on the disk seems like an odd result. Maybe the backup.data file that I created using dd is in a format that doesn't lend itself to `strings`?

Comment: Actually I have just been saved by PHPStorm's Local History feature. It has allowed me to restore everything! Incredible. I will keep this post open since maybe there will be some good answers about data recovery.